# Can uEye_cam capture image with zoom in or out

Tags: ros, ueye-cam, camera, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have connected the uEye_cam with ROS but the image is too large, so I want to zoom it out a little bit so that it can get more information from the environment. But the functions in uEye_cam don't have a "zoom" function. So I am wondering if this can be done using image_transport or image_pipeline or some other functions. Please help me. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128526/can-ueye_cam-capture-image-with-zoom-in-or-out/) by [Jianyuan Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/11541/jianyuan-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [the wiki page, section 2.3](http://wiki.ros.org/ueye_cam):

If you want to downsize the image while preserving the field of view, change one or multiple of the 'sensor_scaling' / 'binning' / 'subsampling' ROS parameters (e.g. set sensor_scaling=2 works in all uEye cameras that I've used).

If however you want to zoom digitally into a portion of the image, you can tweak the 'image_height', 'image_width', 'image_left', and 'image_right' ROS parameters.

Note that you can play with all of these parameters, and more, while running ueye_cam live, using [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure).

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2014-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0